# Rust "+=" operation not returning i32

Tags: rust

```
pub fn max_profit(prices: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut max_overall = 0;
    let mut max_at_i =  0;

    for i in 1..prices.len() {
        max_at_i = cmp::max(0, max_at_i += prices[i] - prices[i-1]);
        max_overall = cmp::max(max_overall,max_at_i);
    }
    
    return max_overall;
}
```

I'm practicing leetcode and went through a solution. For some reason it's saying that "max_at_i += prices[i] - prices[i-1]" in the max function is expecting i32, but instead received "()". But when I change the for loop to

```
for i in 1..prices.len() {
        max_at_i += prices[i] - prices[i-1];
        max_at_i = cmp::max(0, max_at_i);
        max_overall = cmp::max(max_overall,max_at_i);
    }
```

it works perfectly fine. Why is this an issue?

Answer (score 5):

Unlike C, in Rust all assignment operators return `()`, not the assigned value.

Comment: I think that's a good change, actually using the result of `+=` or `++` can lead to very subtle errors that are hard to find.

Comment: @Finomnis It's also impossible to implement returning the value if the left-hand side isn't `Copy`, which `AddAssign`, etc. don't require.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I looked at another stack post and was actually able to return the value by doing "max_at_i = cmp::max(0, {max_at_i += prices[i] - prices[i-1]; max_at_i});"

Comment: Sure, that works. From a readability and code quality point of view, it's worse than the suggested change in your question, though. I think the pattern you show here is horrible, there really is no reason why you shouldn't write this in two lines instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your original code, the `+=` there serves no purpose.

Why don't you just replace `+=` with `+`, as you overwrite the variable in the same line anyway?

```rust
pub fn max_profit(prices: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut max_overall = 0;
    let mut max_at_i =  0;

    for i in 1..prices.len() {
        max_at_i = cmp::max(0, max_at_i + prices[i] - prices[i-1]);
        max_overall = cmp::max(max_overall,max_at_i);
    }
    
    return max_overall;
}
```

Comment: I was actually wondering the same thing when looking at the solution. Although, I know that + won't working after running an example, I can't really articulate/formulate why this is the case and why += is necessary, other than the fact you won't get the correct output. The leetcode question is 121 and the solution I looked at is kadane's algorithm, the most popular post. Hopefully you'll be able to make sense of it.